# Cannot set property Id value in EF CORE if property is included in select

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I am using Entity Framework 2.0.1 and I have having a problem that was working fine in pre 2.x versions of EF.

If I select an object and include a property in the selection and I want to update that property, I must update the object reference, not the Id referencing the object for EF to recognize and save the change.

Here is an example. 
Ranking.RankTypeId is a foreign key to RankType.RankTypeId. I select and include the RankType property.

```
public Ranking GetRankingById(int rankingId)
{
    using (var context = new BestNetDatabaseContext())
    {
        var rankings = context.Rankings.AsQueryable();

        var foundRanking = rankings.Include(x => x.RankType).FirstOrDefault(x => x.RankingId == rankingId);

        if (foundRanking == null)
            throw new RankingNotFoundException();

        return foundRanking;
    }
}
```

If I want to update the Ranking.RankType, I must select and get an instance of the RankType object and set that.

```
ranking.RankType = _rankTypeService.GetRankTypeById(1);
```

What I would like to do (and have been doing for years) is just set the Id.

```
ranking.RankTypeId = 1;
```

I am attaching the object to the context and setting the state to dirty before saving changes (this code was working in previous versions of EF CORE).

```
public void UpdateRanking(Ranking ranking)
{
    using (var context = new MyDatabaseContext())
    {
        context.Rankings.Attach(ranking);
        context.Entry(ranking).State = EntityState.Modified; 
        //ranking.RankTypeId IS correctly set to 1 at this point
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

If I do not use the include statement, I can set the Id and EF will recognize the change and update the database fine. It just seems to ignore updating the Id when I include the property. Thoughts?

Comment: Are you sure there is RankType with id of (1)??

Comment: They changed many things in that area, apparently including the priority of what is considered modified when both navigation and FK properties have values and navigation property key is different from the FK property value. In general this is ambiguous case, thus can be handled one or the another way, but at least it should be documented, and I can't find any documentation about that behavior and why / when it has been changed. Too bad for people trying to use EF Core in production.

Comment: Yeah, there is a RankType of 1.

I agree with you. Documentation is not the best. Thanks for your thoughts.